# Getting PID of MPlayer (without filtering all processes or loosing keyboard control)

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I'm frequently running some kids show, while I work. To do that, I need to extend screen to tv, change audio sink etc. AND move mplayer window from primary screen to desired + make that window sticky. I know how to do all of that, and I can write that script. But to do all of that, I need PID for just executed MPlayer. However if I run MPlayer from inside of bash script like `mplayer ... &` I can get PID via `$!` but I lose ability to control the mplayer when the script ends. I know about possiblity to execute mplayer via `-slave` option, but I'd like to control it in same manner as if you start MPlayer normally.

Does anyone know how to invoke MPlayer in bash script, be able to get it's PID and be able to control MPlayer via normal MPlayer console interaction when the script ends?

I'm open to other solutions as well, but essentially I need to start mplayer somehow first, then get it's PID to be able to run pacmd and wmctrl commands, and all of that without changing behavior of executed mplayer.

Comment: if you run MPlayer in bash like `mplayer ... &` you will lose the ability to control it. It just runs in background after the bash script ends. Otherwise it 'works', yes, no need for extra file.

Comment: `mplayer & disown $!`   or  maybe you can invoke it via `tmux`  or `sceen`

Comment: @Jetchisel running mplayer in screen works, I can reconnect to it and control the mplayer. Great! But how to get PID then? I tried `screen -S mpl -p mpl -d -m mplayer movie.avi & echo $!\;fg` and not PID printed in screen ... Disown didn't work for me at all

Comment: I don't kow if that will work, since I have not done it that way.  but once my app is up and running I can get the pid via `pgrep -xn mplayer`

Comment: yes sure, but is it _that_ mplayer you just started? Imagine you have multiple audio sink machine, and with tv connected via hdmi everyone has that machine, and while you want to continue listening lecture or whatever you're just doing, you want your kid have some fairytale on tv. Without hickup to your mplayer or quessing pid. Kamils solution below looks very promising, have to tests it.

Comment: If that solution works for you then sure.

Comment: I appreciate your help also, that has to be said. Thank you! I didn't know about -n flag of pgrep. Yes, most probably your solution would work as well.

Comment: Well, I personally doubt that my solution will work compared to what `@Kamil Maciorowski` did/post as answer, that's why I did not post mine :-), Glad you  have it sorted out now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script below executes the following procedure:

1. Save the original stdin for later use. In your use case it most likely points to the terminal.
2. Redirect stdin from `/dev/null`, so no process (including future children) uses the original one by default. Note processes that access `/dev/tty` directly (e.g. `sudo` asking for a password) may still interfere.
3. Run `mplayer` in the background with stdin redirected to the original one. This way it's the only process that uses it. Command line arguments are passed as-is.
4. Wait for the right window to appear.
5. Do what you want to do.
6. Wait for `mplayer` to exit.

If `mplayer` exits prematurely then the script will never pass beyond "wait for the right window". Therefore it's good to execute few steps in a subshell in the background. When `mplayer` exits, the main script should not let the subshell survive.

The script will misbehave if job control is enabled, so do not source it from a shell with job control. If sourced, it can also `kill` more than you expect. You should run the script as a standalone executable.

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'kill 0' EXIT     # do not let children survive

manage_mp() {
   # wait for window to appear
   until wmctrl -lp | grep -q '\b'"$mppid"'\b.*\bMPlayer\b'; do sleep 1; done

   # do whatever you want to do; the PID is in $mppid in case you lose $!
   # test line below
   wmctrl -r MPlayer -b add,above
}


exec 17<&0             # save stdin
exec 0</dev/null       # redirect stdin, so the original is not used

<&17 mplayer "$@" &    # run mplayer in background
mppid="$!"

manage_mp &

wait "$mppid"          # wait for mplayer
```

Comment: VERY nice and educative, I learned a lot from this! It just works, no complaints. Just let me ask few things. Why is that redirections necessary, what is happening behind the scenes? Since without it, mplayer cannot be controlled if it's not the last command in the script. And if it is, for some reason quitting mplayer won't get me back 'cursor' immediately,and I have to press enter first to get it back.And if MPlayer is not the last command,even if it's followed just by variable assignment,I'm not able to control the mplayer.Can you explain?And if I need to use sudo (I don't) it's impossible?

Comment: @MartinMucha When `&` is used (and job control is disabled), the shell redirects stdin to `/dev/null` or equivalent file, before performing explicit redirections. Then `mplayer` cannot read from the terminal. In our case our redirection wins. I'm not sure about "if not the last command", cannot replicate fully. I make sure `mplayer` is the only process that uses the original stdin, so other processes (that you may want to start in the script in the foreground) do not compete for input. //  See `man 8 sudo`, `-S` and `-A` options.

Comment: Thanks you very much! I adapted it for my usecase adding some more commands and replacing `-r MPlayer` with window ID, and it works like a charm! Great lecture on bash. Thanks!